# Escape $ dollar sign from linux/Unix argument

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Hi all I have one linux script which takes parameter from datastage.

In my script
Variable password=$4 ($4 value from datastage which is my db password)

And my db password consists of 'abc$' sign in it.
When I echo $pass or $4 the output is abc which is causing problem.
Is there anyway to escape $ sign in arguments.
I want output as abc$

Comment: Is there anything after `$` sign? Please post the exact commands you are executing. `my db password consists of 'abc$' ` How do you call your command? Please post the command line.

Comment: No there is nothing after $ sign
I am connecting to DB2 via Unix and my password value I am fetching from datastage
I am using below command DB2 connect to database user $user using $password which is (abc$)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre], i.e. a minimal script that reproduces the problem and the corresponding input. Don't use comments to answer requests for information or clarification.

Comment: The _only_ thing you need to do is quote `"$password"` **everywhere** you use it.